# Sql, do one expression if other expression is true

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement

i need to call my db to see if any user with parentId = 30 is there.
if there is, i wanna do one expression. if not, i wanna do another.

sometime like this below. please note that this is just a sample to explain what i'm trying to do.

```
Select count(*) as Users from user where parentID = 30
When Users > 0
     Select * from user where parentID = 30
else
     Select * from user
```

Hope it's the question is explain properly.

Comment: Do you need a different expression in a column, or to perform a different query?

Comment: @JiriTousek i need to perform a different query if then statement is true

Comment: Also please add the DB type you're using, unless you're asking for ANSI SQL solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
Select * from tbl 
where parentID = 30 
or ((select count(*) as Users from tbl where parentID = 30) <= 0)
```

Either the parentid is 30 and only that record is retrieved, or there are no records with that parentid, so all records are retrieved. Note that this will work on SQL Server, Oracle and MySQL.

**NOTE**: This works because both queries in your example return the same columns. You need to specify if you are expecting different columns in each query for actual use.

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/874b44/1)

**Update**: Since you are using SQL Server, you can simply store the count in a variable and use if-else to decide which query to run, regardless of what the queries are, like so:

```
declare @count int = 0

select @count = count(*) from user where parentid = 30

if @count > 0
 begin
  select * from user where parentid = 30
 end
else
 begin
  select * from user
 end
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/JKAI40541)

Comment: What if i wanna look up a select in a other tbl if count = 0 ?